# How to use sed or awk to replace string in csv file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Sorry for a really basic question. How to replace a particular column in a csv file with some string?

e.g.

```
id, day_model,night_model
===========================  
1 ,          ,          
2 ,2_DAY     ,          
3 ,3_DAY     ,3_NIGHT         
4 ,          , 
(4 rows)
```

I want to replace any string in the column 2 and column 3 to true 
others would be false, but not the 1,2 row and end row.

Output:

```
id, day_model,night_model
===========================      
1 ,false     ,false
2 ,true      ,false     
3 ,true      ,true         
4 ,false     ,false
(4 rows)
```

What I tried is the following sample code( Only trying to replace the string to "true"  in column 3):

```
#awk -F, '$3!=""{$3="true"}' OFS=, file.csv > out.csv
```

But the out.csv is empty. Please give me some direction.
Many thanks!!

Comment: As you say, it is a really basic question. What have you tried to solve it? Why that doesn't worked for you?

Comment: I have tried some code but it does not work. Especially for the if and else part.

Comment: @hismart: Then post it before you are victim of **down votes**. Are there only three columns ?

Comment: I have post that. Plz help, thanks a lot

Comment: @noob yes, only 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your field separator is comma, the "empty" fields may contain spaces, particularly the 2nd field. Therefore they might not equal the empty string.

I would do this:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    # ex
    NR>2 && !/^\([0-9]+ rows\)/ {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
            $i = ($i ~ /[^[:blank:]]/) ? "true" : "false"
    }
    { print }
' file
```

Comment: Many thanks! It solve my problem and its really a elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Well since you added `sed` in tag and you have only three columns I have solution for your problem in **four** steps because regex replacement was not possible for all cases in just one go.

Since your 2nd and 3rd column is having blank space. I wrote four `sed` commands to do the replacement for each kind of row.

1. `sed '/^(\d+\s+,)\S+\s*,\S+\s*$/\1true,true/gm' file.txt`

   This will replace rows like `3 ,3_DAY     ,3_NIGHT`

   **[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA2zR9/1)**
2. `sed '/^(\d+\s+,)\S+\s*,\s*$/\1true,false/gm' file.txt`

   This will replace rows like `2 ,2_DAY     ,`

   **[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA2zR9/2)**
3. `sed '/^(\d+\s+,)\s*,\S+\s*$/\1false,true/gm' file.txt`

   This will replace rows like `5 ,          ,2_Day`

   **[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA2zR9/3)**
4. `sed '/^(\d+\s+,)\s*,\s*$/\1false,false/gm' file.txt`

   This will replace rows like `1 ,      ,`

   **[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA2zR9/4)**

Comment: I have learned so much from your demo, thanks for your kindly help!